# Animate UIView to "squiggle" its way to destination instead of going in straight line

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have an animation like this:

```
bubble.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 75, y: -120)

UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 2.5,
    animations: {
        self.bubble.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.height * -1.3)
    }
)
```

However, the animation goes in a straight line. I want the animation to do a little back and forth action on its way to its destination. Like a bubble. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about a spring effect? You could look into either springWithDamping https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-animate-views-with-spring-damping-using-animatewithduration or you could look at easing to either use one of the ready made ones or create your own curve https://medium.com/@RobertGummesson/a-look-at-uiview-animation-curves-part-1-191d9e6de0ab

Comment: @CristianMoisei No. Using a spring effect still makes it go in a straight line. It just bounces (still along a straight line). I want it to move from side to side on its way to its destination. The curve thing still has it going in a straight line too, it just changes the speed of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to animate along a path you can use `CAKeyframeAnimation`. The only question is what sort of `path` do you want. A dampened sine curve might be sufficient:

```
func animate() {
    let box = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    box.backgroundColor = .blue
    box.center = bubblePoint(1)
    view.addSubview(box)

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.path = bubblePath().cgPath
    animation.duration = 5
    box.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

where

```
private func bubblePath() -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: bubblePoint(0))
    for value in 1...100 {
        path.addLine(to: bubblePoint(CGFloat(value) / 100))
    }

    return path
}

/// Point on curve at moment in time.
///
/// - Parameter time: A value between 0 and 1.
/// - Returns: The corresponding `CGPoint`.

private func bubblePoint(_ time: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    let startY = view.bounds.maxY - 100
    let endY = view.bounds.minY + 100
    let rangeX = min(30, view.bounds.width * 0.4)
    let midX = view.bounds.midX

    let y = startY + (endY - startY) * time
    let x = sin(time * 4 * .pi) * rangeX * (0.1 + time * 0.9) + midX
    let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    return point
}
```

Yielding:

[image]